# XPages save a number forced to 2sp

Tags: xpages

How can I force a number entered by a user to be saved as 2dp? I can set the display, but I actually want it saved with 2dp anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you want to store 2 decimal points precision (and cut off / round off anything longer). In the Notes documents there is no precision setting for a number, it will always be stored as received from the XPage. You have a number of options:

- Use a custom input filter to manipulate the number (cut/round, no point padding with 0 after the . )
- Round it in the post-change event
- Round it in the querySave event
- Use a @Formula in the original form and set the property to compute with form (slowest)